# Varnish 3 VCL Config to Cache Only Home Page - Not Working

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to cache only the home page (for test purposes) with Varnish. 
I want to cache the home page only for anonymous users at the moment. To do this, I want to ignore the cache if there's a cookie named 'sessionid'.

Also, Django's backend is always sending the Varying: cookie header, which I want to remove, because Varnish will produce a different cache for every combination of cookies. And this combination changes all the time, because the be is always sending the 'csrf' cookie too, which is always different.

In summary:

- Cache only home page
- Cache only for anonymous users (when sessionid cookie is not present)
- Remove the Varying header

Server configuration:

---

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

---

### VCL:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8000";
}

sub vcl_recv
{
    if (! req.http.Authorization ~ "Basic xxxxxxxxx=")
    {
      error 401 "Restricted";
    }

    # caching only home page
    if (! req.url == "/" || req.http.Cookie ~ "sessionid" || req.request == "POST") {
        return(pass);
    }

    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

sub vcl_fetch
{
    # Remove 'vary' header if home page is called
    if (bereq.url == "/") {
        unset beresp.http.Vary;
        set beresp.ttl = 20m;
    }

}

sub vcl_error
{
    if (obj.status == 401) {
      set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
      set obj.http.WWW-Authenticate = "Basic realm=Secured";
      synthetic {" 

     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">

     <HTML>
     <HEAD>
     <TITLE>Error</TITLE>
     <META HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Type' CONTENT='text/html;'>
     </HEAD>
     <BODY><H1>401 Unauthorized (varnish)</H1></BODY>
     </HTML>
     "};
      return (deliver);
    }    
}
```

---

This configuration worked on Varnish 4, but doesn't seems to work on Varnish 3 (with minor modifications).

To know that it doesn't work, looking at the response from the server, I see the 'age' header which is always at 0.

Here's the request/response details:

### Response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:10808
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 22 Oct 2015 08:32:41 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie:csrftoken=UFON6QI7JHAOVDAOk2fusWtZirOF3dlc; expires=Thu, 20-Oct-2016 08:32:41 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Varnish:1495644039
```

---

### Request headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-CA,en;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
Authorization:Basic xxxxxx=
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:csrftoken=iclCbw25qRf25gYscUVyM1P6mHItWXPq
DNT:1
Host:dev.xxxxxx.com
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
```

---

Comment: Post the Varnish 3 configuration that's not working - let's see what "minor modifications" means.

Comment: This is the 'not working' configuration. Note that I just modified it, but it doesn't change anything.  unset req.http.Cookie; was unset 'req.http.cookie;' (in lower caps). I added stuff for authentication too. It's still not caching anything on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working configuration. I honestly don't know what's the part that made it work.

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8000";
}

sub vcl_recv
{
    set req.backend = default;

    if (! req.http.Authorization ~ "Basic xxxxxxx=")
    {
      error 401 "Restricted";
    }

    # caching only home page
    if (req.url != "/" || req.http.Cookie ~ "sessionid" || req.request == "POST") {
        return(pass);
    }

    unset req.http.cookie;

    return(lookup);
}

sub vcl_fetch
{
    # Remove 'vary' header if home page is called
    if (bereq.url == "/") {
        set beresp.ttl = 20m;
    }

    unset beresp.http.Vary;    
    return(deliver);

}

sub vcl_deliver 
{    
    return(deliver);
}


sub vcl_hit 
{
    return(deliver);
}


sub vcl_error
{
    if (obj.status == 401) {
      set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
      set obj.http.WWW-Authenticate = "Basic realm=Secured";
      synthetic {" 

     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">

     <HTML>
     <HEAD>
     <TITLE>Error</TITLE>
     <META HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Type' CONTENT='text/html;'>
     </HEAD>
     <BODY><H1>401 Unauthorized (varnish)</H1></BODY>
     </HTML>
     "};
      return (deliver);
    }    
}
```